# Implement Custom LWC Lookup dependent on a Picklist value

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm working on an LWC component where in I have implemented a SLDS table with picklist and a custom LWC lookup component.
The ask is, lookup component should filter records based on picklist value selected.
The object for which we're displaying the rows has an Account (Wholesaler) and Account Location lookup (Warehouse) and using LWC, we should be able to select Warehouses depending on the Wholesaler selected on the table.
Could you please help here. I'm not able to figure out how to pass the updated wholesaler value to custom LWC lookup component once the picklist is updated?

**Main Component**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Lightning Web Component using Quick Action">
        <div class="slds-table_edit_container slds-is-relative slds-var-p-around_medium">
            <table aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-table slds-no-cell-focus slds-table_bordered slds-table_edit slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_resizable-cols " role="grid" style="width:100%" aria-label="Example default inline edit table with cell focused">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <!--<th class="slds-hidden" scope="col" style="width:0.1rem">
                        <span id="column-group-header1" class="slds-assistive-text">Line Item Id</span>
                    </th>-->
                    <th class="" scope="col" style="width:2rem">
                        <div class="slds-th__action slds-th__action_form">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Account Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">Product Name</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Account Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">National ID</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Wholesaler</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Quantity" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">Warehouse</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody > 
            <template for:each={itemList} for:item="currentItem"> 
                <tr aria-selected="false" class="slds-hint-parent" key={currentItem.index}  data-key={currentItem.index} >
                    <!--<td class="slds-hidden" role="gridcell" scope="row" data-label="Sr No" >
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.recordId} data-id={currentItem.index} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>-->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit slds-var-m-horizontal_medium" style="vertical-align: middle;" role="gridcell" scope="row" data-label="checkbox" >
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="" name="checkbox" value=true data-id={currentItem.recordId}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Product Name Cell -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit slds-cell-wrap" role="gridcell">
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.productName} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Product National ID Cell -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell">
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <div class="slds-hidden">
                                <p><lightning-formatted-text class="slds-hidden" value={currentItem.recordId} data-id={currentItem.recordId} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                            </div>
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.nationalID}></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Wholesaler Lookup -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" scope="row">
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="wholesaler"
                            value={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            placeholder="Select Wholesaler"
                            options={wholesalerList}
                            onchange={handleWholesalerChange} 
                            row-index={currentItem.index} 
                            data-id={currentItem.recordId}></lightning-combobox>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Warehouse Lookup -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell" scope="row">
                        <!--
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="warehouse"
                            value={currentItem.warehouseId}
                            placeholder="Select Warehouse"
                            options={dependentWarehouses}
                            onchange={handleWarehouseChange} ></lightning-combobox>
                        -->
                        <c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component 
                            name = "warehouse"
                            label = ""
                            placeholder = "Search Warehouse"
                            default-record-id = ""
                            data-wholesalerid ={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            wholesaler-id ={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            onlookupupdate={lookupRecord}
                            row-index={currentItem.index} 
                            data-id={currentItem.recordId}></c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component >
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update" onclick={updateLineItems} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

**Main Component JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import initRecords from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getLineItemsTest';
import getWholesalers from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getWholesalers';

export default class SCT_WholesalerCongaCartComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track data;
    @track columns;
    @track itemList;
    @track wholesalerList;
    @track wholesalers;
    @track warehousesMap;
    @track selectedWholesaler;
    @track dependentWarehouses;
    @track lineItemList;
    
    @wire(initRecords, { cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4' })
    wiredLineItems({data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.itemList = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            
            let tempList = [];
            for(let key in data){
                tempList.push(this.itemList[key].recordId);
            }
            this.lineItemList = tempList;

        } else if(error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.itemList = undefined;
        }
    }

    @wire(getWholesalers, { cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4'}) 
    wiredWholesalers({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.wholesalers = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            let tempOptions = [];

            for(let key in data){
                tempOptions.push({label : data[key].Name, value : data[key].Id});
            }
            this.wholesalerList = tempOptions;

        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.wholesalers = undefined;
        }
    }

    /*
    @wire(getWarehouses , {cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4'})
    wiredWarehouses({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.warehousesMap = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            for(let key in warehousesMap) {
                this.warehousesMap[key].values.forEach(option => {
                    dependentWarehouses.push({
                        label: option.locationName,
                        value: option.locationId 
                    });
                });
            }
            console.log('warehousesMap : '+warehousesMap);
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }*/

    handleWholesalerChange(event) {
        
        this.selectedWholesaler = event.detail.value;
        let dependValues = [];

        console.log(this.selectedWholesaler);
        console.log('event.detail prod',JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log('event detail dataset', JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset.id));
        const index = event.target.dataset.id;

        const checkbox = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-id="'+index+'"]');

        checkbox.checked = true;

        const warehouseLookup =  this.template.querySelectr('c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component[data-id="'+index+'"]');
        warehouseLookup.setAttribute('data-wholesalerid',this.selectedWholesaler);
        
        /*
        console.log(warehousesMap);
        console.log('dependentWarehouses : '+dependentWarehouses);

        if(this.selectedWholesaler) {
            this.warehousesMap[this.selectedWholesaler].values.forEach(singleWarehouse => {
                dependValues.push({
                    label: singleWarehouse.locationName,
                    value: singleWarehouse.locationId
                });
            });
            this.dependentWarehouses = dependValues;
            console.log(this.dependentWarehouses);
        }*/
    }

    lookupRecord(event){
        alert('Selected Record Value on Parent Component is ' +  JSON.stringify(event.detail.selectedRecord));
    }

    handleWarehouseChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    updateLineItems(event) {
        console.log('Save Button Clicked!!!');
        console.log('Save Button Clicked Again!!!');
        console.log('list variable ',this.lineItemList);
        console.log(this.lineItemList.length);
        for(let i=0;i<this.lineItemList.length;i++) {
            this.lineItemId = this.lineItemList[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Lookup Component**

```
<!--
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
-->
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult}  data-source="lookupContainer">      
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">{label}</label>
          <div class="lookupInputContainer slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox"> 
           <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
              <div class="searchBoxWrapper slds-show">
                <!--Lookup Input Field-->
                <lightning-input                   
                   type="search"
                   data-source="searchInputField"
                   onclick={toggleResult}
                   onchange={handleKeyChange}
                   is-loading={isSearchLoading}
                   value={searchKey}
                   variant="label-hidden"
                   placeholder={placeholder}
               ></lightning-input>  
              </div>
              
            <!--Lookup Selected record pill container start-->  
            <div class="pillDiv slds-hide">        
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-combobox__input-entity-icon">
                <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>  
              </span>
              <input type="text"
                     id="combobox-id-1"
                     value={selectedRecord.locationName}       
                     class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value"
                     readonly
                     />
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option">
              <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="close icon" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-icon> 
             </button>
            </div>  
            </div>
        
            <!-- lookup search result part start-->
            <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-5" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                <template for:each={lstResult} for:item="obj">
                <li key={obj.locationId} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                  <div data-recid={obj.locationId} onclick={handelSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                      <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                          <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                      </span>
                    </span>
                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                      <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.locationName}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                </template>
                <!--ERROR msg, if there is no records..-->
                <template if:false={hasRecords}>
                  <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records Found....</li>
                </template>
              </ul>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </template>
```

**Custom Lookup Component JS**

```
/*
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
*/
import { LightningElement,api,wire} from 'lwc';
// import apex method from salesforce module 
import fetchLookupData from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getLookupWarehouses';
import fetchDefaultRecord from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getDefaultedWarehouse';

const DELAY = 300; // dealy apex callout timing in miliseconds  

export default class CustomLookupLwc extends LightningElement {
    // public properties with initial default values 
    @api label = 'custom lookup label';
    @api placeholder = 'search...'; 
    @api iconName = 'standard:account';
    @api sObjectApiName = 'Apttus_Config2__AccountLocation__c';
    @api defaultRecordId = '';
    @api wholesalerId = '';

    // private properties 
    lstResult = []; // to store list of returned records   
    hasRecords = true; 
    searchKey=''; // to store input field value    
    wholesalerActualId=''; // to store input field value    
    isSearchLoading = false; // to control loading spinner  
    delayTimeout;
    selectedRecord = {}; // to store selected lookup record in object formate 

   // initial function to populate default selected lookup record if defaultRecordId provided  
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('wholesalerId  : ');
        console.log(this.wholesalerId);
        this.wholesalerActualId = this.wholesalerId;
        if(this.defaultRecordId != ''){
            fetchDefaultRecord({ warehouseId: this.defaultRecordId })
            .then((result) => {
                if(result != null){
                    this.selectedRecord = result;
                    this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.selectedRecord = {};
            });
        }
    }

    // wire function property to fetch search record based on user input
    @wire(fetchLookupData, { wholesalerId : '$wholesalerActualId' , searchKey: '$searchKey'  })
     searchResult(value) {
        const { data, error } = value; // destructure the provisioned value
        this.isSearchLoading = false;
        if (data) {
            this.hasRecords = data.length == 0 ? false : true; 
            this.lstResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log('(error---> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    };
       
    // update searchKey property on input field change  
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        // Debouncing this method: Do not update the reactive property as long as this function is
        // being called within a delay of DELAY. This is to avoid a very large number of Apex method calls.
        this.isSearchLoading = true;
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        const searchKey = event.target.value;
        const wholesalerActualId = this.wholesalerId;
        console.log('test: '+ wholesalerActualId);
        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
        this.wholesalerActualId = wholesalerActualId;
        }, DELAY);
    }

    // method to toggle lookup result section on UI 
    toggleResult(event){
        const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer');
        const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
        const whichEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-source');
        switch(whichEvent) {
            case 'searchInputField':
                clsList.add('slds-is-open');
               break;
            case 'lookupContainer':
                clsList.remove('slds-is-open');    
            break;                    
        }
    }

    // method to clear selected lookup record  
    handleRemove(){
        this.searchKey = '';    
        this.selectedRecord = {};
        this.lookupUpdatehandler(undefined); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 

        // remove selected pill and display input field again 
        const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapper');
            searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-hide');
            searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-show');

            const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDiv');
            pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-show');
            pillDiv.classList.add('slds-hide');
    }

    // method to update selected record from search result 
    handelSelectedRecord(event){   
        var objId = event.target.getAttribute('data-recid'); // get selected record Id 
        this.selectedRecord = this.lstResult.find(data => data.locationId === objId); // find selected record from list 
        this.lookupUpdatehandler(this.selectedRecord); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 
        this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
    }

    /*COMMON HELPER METHOD STARTED*/

    handelSelectRecordHelper(){
        this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer').classList.remove('slds-is-open');

        const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapper');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-show');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-hide');

        const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDiv');
        pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-hide');
        pillDiv.classList.add('slds-show');     
    }

    // send selected lookup record to parent component using custom event
    lookupUpdatehandler(value){    
        const oEvent = new CustomEvent('lookupupdate',
        {
            'detail': {selectedRecord: value}
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more information/clarification is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wholesaler-id attribute you are already passing the wholesaler-id which is anyway reactive.. You can use that directly in @wire or if you have additional logic you can use setter for this attribute to call any method..
In handleWholesalerChange, you just need to update itemList specific object..

Below is just indicative.. Not tested.

```
let itemList = [
    {index: 1, wholesalerId: 'abc'},
    {index: 2, wholesalerId: 'dec'},
    {index: 3, wholesalerId: 'xyz'}
]
ind = // calculate currentRow Index based on dataset.id
let curRow = itemList.find(item => ind == item.index);
curRow.wholesalerId = selectedWholesalerId;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. I tried this but it is not working.

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the earlier comment. I tested it after some time and it worked. Instead of passing all the data as the list itself, I added the data in an array and used your approach. It worked! Thanks a lot!